# Why is the covariance of the hypergeometric distribution not dependent i and j?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, covariance

Suppose we have $\{1,\ldots,20\}$ and $X_i$ will be the drawn element number $i$ without placing it back (hypergeometric distribution)

My question is why is the covariance $\textbf{cov}=[X_i,X_j]$ for ($1\le i\neq j \le 20$) not dependent on $i$ and $j$?

I also don't understand covariance at all, expectation and variance is understable

Comment: Because the in this situation the distribution of $(X_i,X_j)$ does not depend on $(I, j)$ (that is even stronger).

Answer (score 2):

Note: You are missing some information; I have added the necessary details in **bold**.

> Suppose we **select $n$ elements from** $\{1,\ldots,20\}$, and $X_i$ will be the **indicator random variable that we have** drawn element number $i$ without placing it back (hypergeometric distribution.)
>
> My question is why is the covariance $\textsf{Cov}[X_i,X_j]$ for ($1\le i\neq j \le 20$) not dependent on $i$ and $j$?

From the definition of covariance, and the fact that these are **indicator random variables**.

$$\begin{split}\mathsf {Cov}(X_i,X_j) &= \mathsf E(X_iX_j)-\mathsf E(X_i)\mathsf E(X_j)\\ &= \mathsf P(X_i=1,X_j=1)-\mathsf P(X_i=1)\;\mathsf P(X_j=1) \\ &= \frac 1{n(n-1)}-\frac 1n\cdot\frac 1 n & \text{ if } 0\leqslant i\neq j\leqslant 20\\ &= \frac 1{n^2(n-1)} \end{split}$$

The probabilities that the numbers are selected do not depend on the values of the numbers, only that they are different (and from the set, of course).   Ergo, neither does the covariance.

Comment: Maybe, Graham. But I would not exclude the possibility that $X_i$ denotes the element drawn at $i$-th draw. The OP should clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_i$ denotes the element drawn at $i$-th draw then for distinct elements $r,s$ of $\{1,\dots,20\}$:$$P(X_i=r, X_j=s)=P(X_i=r)P(X_j=s\mid X_i=r)=\frac1{20}\frac1{19}$$So the distribution (and consequently covariance ) do not depend on $i, j$.